# Fixing `MulterError: Unexpected Field`

Tags: reactjs, sequelize.js, multer

I'm building an app (postgres, express, react, node) where I can upload + import excel file into a postgresql database. I'm using the `bulkCreate`method in sequelize to save all transaction data in a `transaction` array, which will be then used for dataviz. However, when I try to read the contents of my excel file in workman with the URL `http://localhost:3003/admin/api/excel/upload` (POST request), I get a `MulterError: unexpected field` and this is my stack trace (i'm not quite sure what's happening because all of my errors are pointing to the node_modules folder):

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at Busboy.emit (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at HeaderParser._finish (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:40:12)
    at SBMH.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at SBMH._sbmh_feed (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:159:14)
    at SBMH.push (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:56:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:46:19)
    at Dicer._oninfo (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:197:25)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (/Users/clauds/Documents/projects/licensing_web/server/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:127:10)
```

here is the portion of my code that uses multer/sequelize:

upload.js

```
const multer = require('multer')

const excelFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (
      file.mimetype.includes("excel") ||
      file.mimetype.includes("spreadsheetml")
    ) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb("Please upload only excel file.", false);
    }
  };

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, __basedir + '/resources/file_uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file.originalname)
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-companyname-${file.originalname}`)
    },
})

var uploadFile = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: excelFilter })
module.exports = uploadFile
```

controller.js

```
const db = require('../models')
const Transaction = db.transaction;

const readXlsxFile = require("read-excel-file/node");

const upload = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.file == undefined) {
      return res.status(400).send("Please upload an excel file!");
    }

    let path =
      __basedir + "/resources/file_uploads/" + req.file.filename;

    readXlsxFile(path).then((rows) => {
      // skip header
      rows.shift();

      let transactions = [];

      rows.forEach((row) => {
        let transaction = {
          date: row[0],
          content: row[1],
          deposit: row[2],
          fin_price: row[3],
          transaction_date: row[4],
        };

        transactions.push(transaction);
      });

      Transactions.bulkCreate(transaction)
        .then(() => {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: "Fail to import data into database!",
            error: error.message,
          });
        });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Could not upload the file: " + req.file.originalname,
    });
  }
};

const getTransactions = (req, res) => {
  Transaction.findAll()
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving transaction data.",
      });
    });
};

module.exports = {
  upload,
  getTransactions,
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Show your middleware where you pass multer logic. Multer throws this error if field name doesn't match with specified one or when you trying to upload more than specified: Your code should be like this:

```
uploadFile().array('fieldName', 5) // instead of 5 any integer
// or if you trying to upload single file
uploadFile().single('fieldName')
```

So in your workman or postman (http client app) specify file input name as specified in multer middleware, otherwise its gonna throw error

Answer (score 1):

Example:  if upload.single("**productName**"), the value should be the same as your req.body, that is req.body.**productName**